# add a click event after deleting list

Tags: reactjs

i have created a fuction in which onClick i delete movie but I also want to add a add  button by which clicking on add button i get my deleted movie back
here is my code

```
class Movies extends Component {
  state = {
    movies: getMovies(),
  };
  handleDelete=(movi)=>{
      const movies = this.state.movies.filter(m=> m._id !== movi._id)
      this.setState({movies})
  }
 

  render() {
    return (
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Genre</th>
            <th>Stock</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.state.movies.map((movie) => (
            <tr key={movie._id}>
              <td >{movie.title}</td>
              <td >{movie.genre.name}</td>
              <td >{movie.numberInStock}</td>
              <td >{movie.dailyRentalRate}</td>
              <td  onClick={()=>this.handleDelete(movie)} className="btn  btn-danger btn-outline-warning btn-sm active ">Remove</td>
            </tr>
          ))}

        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok and what have you tried?

Comment: i haven't tried  i want to know how to add

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: getback = (m) => {
    this.handleDelete() !== m.id;
    this.setState({ movies: getMovies() });
  };

Comment: <td
                onClick={() => this.getback(movie)}
                className="btn  btn-danger btn-outline-primary btn-sm active "
              >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to somehow keep track of the movies that you are deleting so that you can reinstate them... 3 Components (App - parent, Movie & Deleted)

Here is your App:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = { movies: getMovies(), deleted: [] };

  handleDelete = id => {
    const movie = this.state.movies.find(movie => movie.id === id);
    this.setState({ deleted: [...this.state.deleted, movie] });
    this.setState({
      movies: this.state.movies.filter(movie => movie.id !== id)
    });
  };

  handleReinstate = id => {
    const movie = this.state.deleted.find(movie => movie.id === id);
    this.setState({ movies: [...this.state.movies, movie] });
    this.setState({
      deleted: this.state.deleted.filter(movie => movie.id !== id)
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Movies</h1>
        {this.state.movies.map(movie => {
          return (
            <Movie
              key={movie.id}
              movie={movie}
              handleDelete={this.handleDelete}
            />
          );
        })}
        <hr />
        <h1>Deleted</h1>
        {this.state.deleted.map(movie => {
          return (
            <Deleted
              key={movie.id}
              movie={movie}
              handleReinstate={this.handleReinstate}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is your Movie:

```
export default function Movie({ movie, handleDelete }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>{movie.title}</h4>
      <button onClick={() => handleDelete(movie.id)}>Delete</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is your Deleted / Reinstate:

```
export default function Deleted({ movie, handleReinstate }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>{movie.title}</h4>
      <button onClick={() => handleReinstate(movie.id)}>Reinstate</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here is a link to a live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-umffju?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63552027/cannot-read-property-of-table-undefined

Answer (score 1):

For this type of problem, here’s what you could do. Store the deleted movies in state with something like this:

```
This.state={
 currentMovies: [list of movies],
 deletedMovies: [list of movies]
}
```

Have an array that stores Json objects like your movies. Then have a function for storing movies that have been deleted:

```
const deleteMoviesArray=[]

deleteMovie(movieData){
  deleteMoviesArray.push(movieData);
  This.setState({
    deletedMovies: deletedMoviesArray
  })
};
```

Now you have stored your deleted movies. To retrieve your deleted movies, you might use a drop down box something like this:

```
<select>
  {
    This.state.deletedMovies.map(data =>(
       <option> {movie.title}</option>
    ))
  }
</select>
```

And once you select one, do a similar thing to what you did with deleted movies, add a movie back to an array of available movies.

If you need your list of deleted movies to persist past a page refresh, you might consider storing that data in session storage:

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem(‘deletedMovieArray’, [list of movie objects])
```

And get them

```
window.sessionStorage.getItem(‘deletedMovieArray’)
```